# Omitting [INTO] in the INSERT ... SELECT statement

Tags: mysql, mysql-5

Does the `INTO` keyword only makes the query more readable, or does it bring another benefits as well? The queries beneath both seem to run equivalently .

```
insert ignore
tbl (type, details)
values ('1', '2');
```

&

```
insert ignore
into tbl (type, details)
values ('1', '2');
```

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/96146de

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the correct answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/233919/insert-vs-insert-into) question - and Bill Karwin's comment on that answer. I was quite surprised to learn that INTO was optional - but indeed it is, although according to the standard it shouldn't be. Amazingly enough, Oracle does require it - must be the only time that Oracle actually enforces one of the ANSI standards where (many*) others leave it optional!

(*) Sybase, MS SQL Server and MySQL amongst others. IBM DB2, Firebird and PostgreSQL seem to enforce the standard.